# Fast Implementation of Prim aLgorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

I was using geeksforgeeks C++ [implementation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-5-prims-minimum-spanning-tree-mst-2/) of Prim's Algorithm but I am getting Time Limit Exceeded in few testcases. So is there any faster implementation? Here is implementation I am currently using. To make question general, which is fastest implementation of Prim Algo in C++?

Comment: You forgot to include your code.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev : No i did not. Click the link under 'implementation' , it will show geeksforgeeks site n in bottom they have written code in C++ :P

Comment: Your question is broad (you have no specific issue beyond "make this lump of code faster") and you're not demonstrating any effort of your own to solve/investigate the problem. You also don't explain what your time limit is or what the test case is that's breaking. As it stands, I don't think this question is a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

This implementation of Prim is very inefficient. On each iteration it looks for the smallest edge doing an iteration over all edges. If you use a [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) for instance you will have an implementation that is asymptotically faster(`m*log(n)` vs `m*n` for your current implementation). Also you are supposed to write your own code not to use something someone's already written for you.

Comment: It's actually O((n+m) log n)

Comment: @NiklasB. of course. Also the second estimate was wrong. I was not very focused when I wrote that apparently. Thank you. I will keep it only `m*log(n)` as for practical cases m > n.

Comment: Thanks Ivaylo. I wrote my own code but it was getting Running time error always and i was in this cycle for 3 days+night , so you can estimate my level of frustation n thats y i looked upon standard implementation (and wrote code after referring this) . Anyways can you link any standard implementation using heaps/priority_queue , i have Team Selection tests in a week for IOI so i cant afford wasting my time writing from scratch,getting errors then debugging. Hope you understand and thanks again :)

Comment: @MaggiIggam linking to an existing implementation will not make it any more easy for you to qualify for IOI. You need **a lot** of practice. Take this from a person who's been competing last 13 years: you can not practice for few days and make it to IOI. Also if you are not able to write a good Prim you are far from the required skills. No offence meant of course.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev :) No offence taken (it wud be stupid if take :P) But its only Graph Theory where i am a total noob and have DP,combi,etc as my strength +i got a perfect score in National level camp entry test , so i suppose i can make it to IOI team. Hence if you could provide a link containing priority queue based implementation, it would help me save lots of time :)

Comment: @maggi use any dijkstra implementation with `set` and modify it. There's almost no difference between the algos. Or use Kruskal, which teaches you dsu at the same time

Comment: @MaggiIggam also there is a built in structure called priority_queue in C++(and PriorityQueue in java). Btw I always implement Kruskal just as Niklas suggests.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks! Yes i have heard few people prefering 'set' over 'priority_queue' implementation, so can you tell me why is it preffered over priority queue?

Comment: @MaggiIggam Because it allows `erase` (so the code is slightly smaller) and is not noticably slower than priority_queue in G++. I guess priority_queue just has a pretty bad implementation. Of course both do the job.